# Cordova iOS single size icon support

Tags: ios, cordova

Does Cordova support single-size icons for iOS and if so, how to add it to config.xml?

I removed all the different icon sizes and just left

`<icon height="1024" src="src/resources/images/Icons/ios/Icon-App-1024x1024.png" width="1024" />`

But either way, I only get the default Cordova icon to display.

If I set it to single size in Xcode it works as expected.

Deployment is through Azure Pipeline, so I can´t set it manually for release.